# fs register(?) in assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm disassembled my program and I'm trying to understand what is it:

```
MOV DWORD PTR FS:[0],ESP
```

What is FS? I searched in google, and I found that is use as extra register. 
But when is it use? Why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10810340/120163

Answer (score 2):

The FS register is aligned with the thread information block, which contains various thread-specific information.

Of particular interest when disassembling is the head of the exception handler chain at offset zero.

Comment: is it handler for FIRST EXCEPTION will occur?

Comment: In a sense, yes. FS:[0] points to the inner-most exception handler structure on stack. It in turn has a pointer to the next one, and so on. Any function that has an exception frame inserts that frame in this chain on entry and removes it again on exit.