# difference between qword [ss: MEM_ADDRESS] and qword [ds: MEM_ADDRESS]

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly

If you look at the following code:

[image: Say hello function]

Memory is referenced using either qword [ss: MEM_ADDRESS] or qword [ds: MEM_ADDRESS]. What is the difference here?

Comment: Just your silly disassembler displaying default segments, which mean nothing in 64 bit mode anyway. Look in the options to disable it. Until you see `fs` or `gs`, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: @Jester can you clarify what ss ds fs and gs mean?

Comment: `ds:` and `ss:` are segment override prefixes, which are unnecessary here as the registers in question use those segments by default. Here's a SO question about `fs` and `gs`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810203/what-is-the-fs-gs-register-intended-for