# What does the declaration“extern struct cpu *cpu asm("%gs:0");” mean？

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly, xv6

When I'm reading the xv6 source code, I'm confused about the syntax of the declaration below. Can anyone explain it to me?

```
extern struct cpu *cpu asm("%gs:0");
```

Comment: `asm` after a variable declaration usually allows you to specify the variable's name for linkage purposes, but in this case, you're not specifying a name at all, but rather a register reference of sorts.

Comment: Next time - please Google first!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you understand what `extern struct cpu *cpu` means.  The question you have is: What does the `asm("%gs:0")` part mean?

This code is using a gcc extension called [asm labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels) to say that the variable `cpu` is defined by the assembler string `%gs:0`.

This is NOT how this extension is intended to be used and is considered a [hack](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2015-08/msg00075.html).

There's an excellent discussion of gs (and fs) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810340/2189500), but in short gs points to the current thread's local storage.  The format of the data at gs depends on your OS (Windows is very different than Linux).  This particular code is saying that at offset `0` from gs, there is a pointer to a `struct cpu`.

Comment: See [discussion on a recent duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917027/what-does-asm-suffix-mean-in-given-code/47917087?noredirect=1#comment82802441_47917087) for cases where the hack either doesn't compile+assemble (32-bit PIC code, or any time the compiler tries to `mov` the address to a register as an immediate), or worse where it compiles but uses the wrong address (64-bit code using RIP-relative addressing)

Answer (score 9):

It is a special case of an [asm label](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html). It instructs the compiler to emit `%gs:0` instead of the usual symbol name if you reference the `cpu` variable. Presumably `%gs` has been previously set up as a per-cpu storage area, with a `struct cpu` pointer at offset zero. The purpose is to allow each cpu to access its own data.

Comment: so this just calls memory that is at 0 bytes offset in segment referenced by gs 'cpu' ?

Comment: I had glanced at the question a bit too quickly to notice how it was being used.

Comment: I would say this is still somewhat of an abuse of the feature. I have a feeling it could make the compiler generate invalid code under circumstances.

Comment: @Jester, I tend to agree. I think there are better ways to go about this, I was laying around to see if I could find a case where this fails (other than what is documented).

Comment: It fails for taking the address, but you probably wouldn't do that knowing that it's not in the same zero based segment. Now, let's see if we can make the compiler take the address as part of an optimization.

Comment: Can't use it with position independent code.in 32-bit code. It will attempt to generate instructions that look like this `%gs:0@GOT(%ebx)` which of course isn't valid. Not an issue with 64-bit code since it will just use RIP relative addressing since the outputted instruction would be ` %gs:0(%rip)`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: It compiles in 64-bit mode, but uses a RIP-relative addressing mode like `movq    %gs:0(%rip), %rax`. https://godbolt.org/g/jSvB2g  (Godbolt doesn't enable `-pie` by default, so this is plain position-dependent code.  disassembly output shows it really is using a rel32 = 0, not using an offset of `-RIP` to encode an absolute address of 0.  i.e. **the linear address is GS_base + RIP**)

Comment: It could fail when optimizing for space, since if multiple loads of `cpu` are necessary, it saves space to load the address of `cpu` into register. Neither GCC nor clang appear to be smart enough to do this but ICC will: https://godbolt.org/g/JkVTW5

Comment: It also breaks `-masm=intel`, unlike normal symbol names.  And it doesn't seem to build with clang at all, because clang really does use it as a symbol name.  (You'd probably have to tell clang not to use its built-in assembler, so the asm has to go through a plain text format.  But clang on godbolt includes literal `""`, so that probably just totally breaks (or get GAS to look for `%gs:0` as a symbol name?)

Comment: @PeterCordes: `GS_base+RIP` is the wrong address. It should be just `GS_base`.

Comment: @R..: That's exactly my point.  Using `... var asm("%gs:0")` in 64-bit code leads to code that compiles, but loads it from the wrong address even with `-fPIC`.

Comment: Slow mods, I've flagged this A for migration to the other 4 days ago,  pfft christmas.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Merger flags usually are delayed because merging posts is irreversible. It does need someone who has some knowledge in the tag to perform the merger. (I did see your flag a few hours after you created it, but decided to move on). That said, as there's only one answer here, if Jester also agrees with the merger, then I can merge them rightaway. (or else, you'll need to wait till another mod sees the flag.)

Comment: Have become a bit more busy @Antti, have enough time to moderate, but not enough to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com). Hopefully, I'll get back to the normal 18hrs a day on Stack Overflow, in a few months. :p