# what does asm suffix mean in given code?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I was learning how xv6 operating system works through MIT's 6.828 course, where in sources I came accross the following line:

```
extern struct cpu *cpu asm("%gs:0");
```

Can anyone please explain what the following line does?